# user authentication using async websocket instead of django channels

Tags: django, websocket

I have a websocket service previously written using python websocket package which can access django models. Is it possible to check if the messages are coming from an authenticated user without using django channels?

Answer (score 0):

Well, no answers, so you get to watch me at work.

- I made an alternative login api rate limited to 3 requests per minute which would return the token if you send it a username and password.
- I changed the django login template to include the token query
- token query works before username and password is posted to the django server
- token is retrieved before login and placed into browser's session storage
- user logs in, websocket page is loaded, we've got the token in the session storage
- websocket connection is created using the token in the session storage so webscoket server now has the token for authentication
- use token for authentication to retrieve the account data on server side and route requests to the websocket object according to that.